# Finding truly unused tables in a database?

Tags: mysql

As a result of terrible maintenance on a Drupal site, especially with regards to modules being disabled and then just removed without installing, I've inherited a site with tables that I am not sure are being used.

Is there a way to add a check to MySQL that can tell me after a month which tables went completely unused for that month?

(That way, I can more or less safely delete them knowing they were never important. Or at least use it as a comparison with the ones I have manually checked for deletion)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL find unused tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014796/mysql-find-unused-tables)

Comment: and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762539/when-was-the-last-time-a-mysql-table-was-accessed